# Is there symbolic or interpretive significance to Pilate addressing Christ as "the Man," "Christ," and "King"?

Tags: jesus, symbolism, pilate

Pilate addressed Jesus using at least the three appellations: "the Man," "Christ," and "King."

Here are the relevant passages (there are others):

> **Matthew 27:17b**: “[Pilate] said to them, 'Whom do you want me to release for you? Barabbas, or **Jesus who is called Christ**?'" (emphasis added).

Note Pilate's words (he seems to be trying to demonstrate Jesus is a mere man unworthy of death):

> **John 19:5**: "When Jesus came out wearing the crown of thorns and the purple robe, Pilate said to them, '**Here is the man!**'"

After the crowd demanded Barabbas instead of Jesus, once again:

> **Matthew 27:22**: "Pilate said to them, 'Then what shall I do with **Jesus who is called Christ?**'"

Pilate appears to have continued to pleas for Christ's freedom:

> **John 19:14b-15**: "And he said to the Jews, '**Behold, your King!**'."

Is there any symbolism in these identifications? In other words, is there anything analogous to, say, "Prophet", "Priest", "King" (as with Jeremiah, Ezekiel, Daniel: a prince of Israel)?

<sub>**Note that I am not asking why Pilate used the terms that he did, only whether there is any symbolism — as there is with the name "Bar-abbas" (son of the father)**.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This is a very thought-provoking question.

I doubt Pilate was aware of the significance of his words, yet the three-fold description of Jesus parallels somewhat the prophecy given in Isaiah 9:6.

> "For unto us a child is born, unto us a son is given: and the
> government shall be upon his shoulder: and his name shall be called
> Wonderful, Counsellor, The mighty God, The everlasting Father, The
> Prince of Peace." (Isaiah 9:6)

In this text, the One addressed is assigned the following titles:

- Child
- Son
- Wonderful Counsellor
- Mighty God
- Everlasting Father
- Prince of Peace

That list can be seen as comprising three pairs of terms.  The first pair (child & son) refer to Christ's humanity (man).  The second pair (Counsellor & God) refer to his divinity (Christ).  The final pair (Father & Prince) address his royalty (King).

We can visualize this easily in a table:

| Humanity | Divinity | Royalty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| child | Wonderful Counsellor | Everlasting Father |
| son | Mighty God | Prince of Peace |
| **man** | **Christ** | **King** |

These are the kinds of questions that represent a deeper look into the things of God, as a miner digging for the precious ore.  Looking at things deeply can be very rewarding for the one who appreciates spiritual things.